Replace characters before a number to a new character after the number python
I have some strings look like: *.rem.1.gz and *.rem.2.gz
And I want to replace it into *.1.trim.gz and *.2.trim.gz
The number 1 and number two files are paired with each other, which I want to create a separate string to include both files at once.
import os
allfiles = os.listdir
pair = [x.replace("rem.(\d+)","(\d+).trim")for x in allfiles] ##obviously this doesn't work but just want to give an idea what I want to do!

Thanks for the help!

I don't think you need regex. Replace rem with trim, split on a period, swap positions, then rejoin the string

(\d+) is not meaningful in the replacement string.  Since you put the original match inside parentheses, making it a capturing group, you can simply refer to it as \1 in the replacement string.  (Note that a raw string literal - r prefix on the string - is required for this to work.)

@OneCricketeer "Replace rem with trim" blindly is dangerous; e.g. it would do the wrong thing for premium_content.rem.1.gz. And while you can do it without regex... why? since this is exactly the kind of thing regex excels at.

You can use (?i)(.*)\.rem\.([0-9]+)\.gz if it is case insensitive or (.*)\.rem\.([0-9]+)\.gz otherwise.
Example
import re

s = "*.rem.1.gz"
p = r'(?i)(.*)\.rem\.([0-9]+)\.gz'
print(re.sub(p, r'\1.\2.trim.gz', s))


Prints
*.1.trim.gz


Using the idea in the following comment, you can simplify the code.

There's no need to capture the base name in a group. Anchor the end of the string with $ instead. – blhsing

Example
import re

s = "*.rem.1.gz"
p = r'(?i)\.rem\.([0-9]+)\.gz$'
print(re.sub(p, r'.\1.trim.gz', s))



There's no need to capture the base name in a group. Anchor the end of the string with $ instead.
